# web api returned content missing when posting in angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post data and return some content posting to a .net web api using angularjs

here is my web api

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(
                "<strong>test</strong>",
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "text/html"
            )
        };
    }
```

and here is my post from my client

```
$http({
                url: 'my happy url',
                method: "POST",
                data: objData,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(headers());
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error");
            });
```

my problem is I do not get any data returned. I am sure I am missing something simple. Thanks for your help.

in the above code the data parameter is empty and I would expect to find the string "**test**" in the data parameter.

Comment: If you print it to console what does it show? undefined?

Comment: so, .success is being called?  You're only logging headers, what about the data parameter?

Comment: Try to console.log() all the parameters in the success function.

Comment: I was looking for results in the data parameter which is empty. I left the headers in as it was the last thing I was using as I was debugging.

Comment: Have you tried to access the WebAPI data via other clients like `PostMan` or `Fiddler`? Did it worked there?

Comment: Postman returns empty, so clearly the problem is on the web api side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of HttpResponseMessage, can you try to use [IHttpActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)? Sample code as below.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostSample()
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Test String");
}
```